# DRF не работают статичные файлы

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, swagger, openapi

[image: Фотография ошибки]

Хочу добавить свой свагер используя схему open api

Вот код url

```
urlpatterns = [
   path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
   path('api/', include('api.urls')),
   path('', include('payments.urls')),
   path('swagger/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='swagger/swagger.html'), 
   name='swagger'),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Статик файлы настроены в settings

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Приложение запускается в докере, статические файлы загружаются в контейнер,  manage.py collectstatic делал, однако всё равно одна и таже ошибка. Помогите решить, в чём проблема не понимаю, вроде всё настроено правильно.

Comment: При чём тут статичные файлы, если ошибка говорит про ненайденный шаблон? Ну а касательно ненайденного шаблона — почему вы решили, что шаблон `swagger/swagger.html` в принципе должен быть?

Comment: Не приводите код картинкой.